# inatalling optaplanner example in eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse, maven, optaplanner

I am trying to install optaplanner examples in eclipse. I got some problem that I am not able to solve:

```
Software:
Eclipse luna
jdk 1.8
maven 1.6
```

I also used `GIT` software for this project.

The main problem is on `ConferenceSchedulingXslxFileIO` java class.
The errors are:

```
The method getLeft() is undefined for the type Talk 
The method getLeft() is undefined for the type Talk 
The method getRight() is undefined for the type Object  

The method getRight() is undefined for the type Object  
The method getRight() is undefined for the type Object  
The method getRight() is undefined for the type Talk    
The method nextTalkListCell(Iterable<Object>) in the
The type Pair does not define getLeft(Object) that is applicable here   
The type Pair does not define getLeft(Object) that is applicable here
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect **your IDE's java language setting might be to too low**. It should be set to at least java 8 compatible. Note that the java language setting differs from the JDK used (but of course, the JDK needs to be 8 at least too).

The getLeft() and getRight() are only used on `Pair` instances. So unless you changed the sources it's somehow not figuring out that some vars are of type Pair and just thinks it's an Object. Lack of generics support or generic typing improvements in recent java language versions might explain that.